# CSS/HTML: indent whole block of text containing hard returns

Tags: css, block, indentation

I want to indent a block of text--all the text, not just the first line--a pretty common thing in layout and word processing programs and am finding this surprisingly difficult with CSS.

I tried `margin-left`, `padding` and `text-indent` without success.  By combining `margin-left` with `display:block-inline`, I managed to get the block to indent but the `display:block-inline` adds a space above the block which throws off layout and generally looks bad.  Apparently, another approach is `<blockquote>` but that is deprecated.  Can anyone suggest a way to do block indent with CSS?  Also I am trying to keep code lightweight so don't want to do a complicated styling of lists as this fits into a larger page. 
 works fine except for this issue. Thanks:

Following code indents block but inserts space above it.

html

```
Colors:<br>
<span style="display:inline-block;margin:1em;">
blue<br>
orange - complement to blue<br>
red<br>
purple - blend of red and blue</br>
</span>
```

Comment: `<span style="display:block; margin-left:1em">` doesn't work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It inserts space because you're setting `margin` to each side of the span (top, left, right, bottom).
Change the style of the span to this:

```
display:inline-block;margin-left:1em;
```